# How to prevent Excess line spacing copying/converting tinyMCE editor content to Word/PDF

Tags: php, pdf, ms-word, tinymce

I am using tinyMCE as an in-app editor within my browser application.
The problem I have is when trying to either copy and paste or use various conversion methods to render the contents of the tinyMCE editor in an MS Word Docx or a PDF.
The paragraph breaks suddenly become twice the height they appear in the tinyMCE editor. *** CORRECTION: There are actually 2 line breaks produced for every paragraph break. ***
Below is an example of one of my init calls. I've tried using settings such as the various force... and remove_linebreaks settings in my example, with no apparent success. 
There was also a suggestion about setting the p tag padding attributes somewhere in the css but couldn't quite figure out where. Any other ideas?

```
     tinymce.init({
     selector: 'textarea#myTextareadisp'+ind,
     theme: 'modern',
     width: nwidth,
     plugins: ['contextmenu paste fullscreen'],
     contextmenu: 'undo | copy selectall | fullscreen preview',
     height: nheight,
     toolbar: false,
     menubar: false,
     statusbar: false,
     force_br_newlines : true,
     force_p_newlines : false,
     forced_root_block : '', // Needed for 3.x
     remove_linebreaks : true,
     forced_root_blocks: false
  });
```

Comment: I've read in other stackoverflow posts that tnyMCE adds a <div> tag around every paragraph when stuff is pasted into the editor. Much of the usage is copy and paste, so that may be the origin of what the Word and PDF files treat as additional line_breaks. Someone suggested making <div> an invalid tag - so that this doesn't happen. Is this the right track?

Comment: Adding the invalid_lements: 'div' setting to my init call seems to have helped. Worried what this will do if someone needs to copy and paste webpage content though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the *on('copy')* event to take control over the content that gets copied and play with that content.

Comment: Sorry. Got very side-tracked and forgot I'd posted this question. Just noticed your answer. Good point I'll look into it.